# How to determine whether a points lies in an ellipse

Tags: r, statistics

I had posted a similar question earlier. I was trying to determine whether a point lies within an ellipse. Basically I generate some bivariate normal data and create an ellipse.
Heres the code I use

```
 library(MASS)
 set.seed(1234)
 x1<-NULL
 x2<-NULL
 k<-1
 Sigma2 <- matrix(c(.72,.57,.57,.46),2,2)
 Sigma2
 rho <- Sigma2[1,2]/sqrt(Sigma2[1,1]*Sigma2[2,2])

 eta<-replicate(300,mvrnorm(k, mu=c(-2.503,-1.632), Sigma2)) 

 p1<-exp(eta)/(1+exp(eta))
 n<-60
 x1<-replicate(300,rbinom(k,n,p1[,1]))
 x2<-replicate(300,rbinom(k,n,p1[,2]))

 rate1<-x1/60
 rate2<-x2/60

 library(car)
 dataEllipse(rate1,rate2,levels=c(0.05, 0.95))
```

I need to find out whether the pair (p1[,1],p1[,2]) lies within the area of the ellipse above.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76457/check-if-a-point-is-within-an-ellipse

Answer (score 7):

`dataEllipse` returns the ellipses as polygons, so you could use the `point.in.polygon` function from the `sp` library to check whether the points are inside the ellipse:

```
ell = dataEllipse(rate1, rate2, levels=c(0.05, 0.95)) 
point.in.polygon(rate1, rate2, ell$`0.95`[,1], ell$`0.95`[,2])
```

---

When I run the following code...

```
library(MASS)
set.seed(1234)
x1<-NULL
x2<-NULL
k<-1
Sigma2 <- matrix(c(.72,.57,.57,.46),2,2)
Sigma2
rho <- Sigma2[1,2]/sqrt(Sigma2[1,1]*Sigma2[2,2])
eta<-replicate(300,mvrnorm(k, mu=c(-2.503,-1.632), Sigma2))
p1<-exp(eta)/(1+exp(eta))
n<-60
x1<-replicate(300,rbinom(k,n,p1[,1]))
x2<-replicate(300,rbinom(k,n,p1[,2]))
rate1<-x1/60
rate2<-x2/60
library(car)
ell = dataEllipse(rate1, rate2, levels=c(0.05, 0.95))
library(sp)
point.in.polygon(rate1, rate2, ell$`0.95`[,1], ell$`0.95`[,2])
```

... I get the following output

```
  [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [56] 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
[111] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
[166] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1
[221] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
[276] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: When I run your code I get all zeros. Not sure I am understanding it. I want to see if the pair (p1[,1],p1[,2])lies in the ellipse. In otherwords how many times does the estimated ellipse cover the true p's                                                            > library(car)
> library(sp)
> ell<-dataEllipse(rate1,rate2,levels=c(0.05, 0.95)) 
> point.in.polygon(rate1, rate2, ell$`0.95`[,1], ell$`0.95`[,2])
  [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  s on

Comment: Thanks for your response.I want to find out how many times in the 300 simulations does the pair (p1[,1],p1[,2]) fall within the Ellipse of (rate1,rate2).

Comment: @user1560215: You can get the count of how many points fall within the ellipse using `count(point.in.polygon...)` (I get `289` for one run), and you can get the probability using `mean(point.in.polygon(...)` (in this case `0.9633`).

Comment: But for the last line of your code instead of point.in.polygon(rate1, rate2, ell$`0.95`[,1], ell$`0.95`[,2]) to find whether the true p's are contained in the estimated ellipse should I be doing                                        point.in.polygon(p1[1,], p1[2,], ell$`0.95`[,1], ell$`0.95`[,2])

Comment: I was hoping to get some help on this. When I run the above code posted by Jake, I get all zeros. But his output shows some 1's. I am just copy pasting the code to R. Any thoughts?

Comment: @user1560215: Maybe you're using an outdated version of `R` or the `sp` package? What output do you get when you do `point.in.polygon(0,0,c(-1,1,1,-1),c(-1,-1,1,1))`

Comment: @user1560215: And running `point.in.polygon(0.2, 0.04, ell$`0.95`[,1], ell$`0.95`[,2])` after the code from my answer gives you `1`, while `point.in.polygon(1, 0.04, ell$`0.95`[,1], ell$`0.95`[,2])` gives you `0`?

Comment: Here is what I get              > point.in.polygon(0.2, 0.04, ell$`0.95`[,1], ell$`0.95`[,2]) 
[1] 0
> point.in.polygon(1, 0.04, ell$`0.95`[,1], ell$`0.95`[,2]) 
[1] 0
> point.in.polygon(0,0,c(-1,1,1,-1),c(-1,-1,1,1))
[1] 1
>

Comment: do you think my getting different results than yours may be a version issue?

Answer (score 1):

Just find C and subtract radius

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you figure out where the foci are located then points whose sum of the inter-focal distance plus the distances to the point from the foci will be a constant on the ellipse and could be used as a test. The example you have hacked together is correct for the degenerate case of a circle where the interfocal distance is zero.

Comment: @DWin lmfao you get a +1 sir

Comment: @DWin also its not just for circle. Consider the radius a variable ammount